# Saved Search - Email fields surrounded by quotes

Tags: netsuite

We currently have saved searches setup to pull inventory from NetSuite.  These saved searches are emailed where the report is sent as a CSV file.  We need to field values to be sent in the CSV with surrounding quotation marks.

For Example:

If we just do a normal saved search our report looks like:

Sku, Qty
ABC123, 5

If we make the results field a Formula(Text) field with something like this as the formula:

Concat('"', Concat({some_field}, '"'))

The output in the report (In the browser) looks like this:
Sku, Qty
"ABC123", 5

The problem we have is that in version with the formula, when the file is actually emailed using the scheduled information it gets exported to CSV and the CSV looks like this:

Sky, Qty
"""ABC""", 5

Netsuite is escaping my quotes in my report on the export.

How do I create this so that the CSV when sent looks like this:
Sky, Qty
"ABC123", 5

Comment: Hello Jake, when you do Export CSV in the saved search page does it have double quotes as well?

Comment: No that is my problem.  When I export a saved search it does not put quotes around the values.  I used the formulaic approach to get the right quotes in the report but when exported it then escapes the quotes and I get the multiple quotes.

Comment: I just tested this and my exported CSV file have the quotes. I'm using formula as you have sampled.

Comment: Are you just opening the file in excel?  Open it in a basic text editor like notepad on windows or textedit on the mac and you will see the extra quotes.